# Min() behaviour in elastic search

Tags: database, elasticsearch

What will the min Aggregation will in return if we are containing one null value and remaining are non null in field.

```
PUT /product_index 
{   "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }   
} }

POST /product_index/_doc/1 
{   "id": "1",   "name": "pant",   "price": 30 } 
POST /product_index/_doc/2 
{   "id": "2",   "name": "shirt",   "price": 300 } 
POST /product_index/_doc/3 
{   "id": "3",   "name": "pant23",   "price": null } 
POST /product_index/_doc/4 
{   "id": "4",   "name": "shirt23",   "price": 40 }
```

What will be the min aggregation in price field will return?

```
sourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("min_price").field("price"));
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
```

I did try anything it just return null , values suspecting that it is due to null value presence in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you always use the same document id, so the same document is updated over and over. If you run the command with the document having price = null, then you have a single document with price = null, hence why min price is null as well.

If you pick a different id for each document, you'll get min_price = 30 as expected.

Comment: Sorry , actually that was typo while posting the question , they are correct and having different ids actaully

Comment: what will id 3 return when i use min aggregate over there?

Comment: When I execute your command above, I get min_price 30, as it should be. The document with the null price is just ignored.

Comment: Thanks for checking , do we have any online playground for es

Comment: Not that I know of.